# What is workflow for connecting with a client's GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

We are a development firm with our own GitLab instance. Up until now, our projects have consisted of two possibilities:

- We develop an entirely new project and maintain the Git project, or
- The client brings us existing code (which has no source control) and we set up a Git project in our GitLab instance.

We have a new client that is a unique situation for us. This client has an existing GitLab instance and maintains the code there.

This is the way I'd like to see the process go:

- They maintain their repo,
- We clone/fork/copy their repo,
- We perform our adjustments on *our* repo, and
- We push those changes to their repo.

As you can tell, my knowledge of the Git vocabulary is poor. What exactly would I request their development team do to get us access?

I've seen this workflow before on open source projects when people fork those projects, but I don't have experience with open source development so am unsure how the underlying infrastructure works.

My main goal is to get the terminology I need to make sure I'm passing the correct requests to the client's team.

---

To clarify, we are welcome to dictate any development terms here, so no restrictions. My main goals:

- I'd like to review all commits before the client has access to them,
- I'd like the client not to have direct access to our developers, and
- I'd like our developers to be pushing to our GitLab instance so they don't need to set up additional infrastructure on their machines.

Comment: well that depends on your work agreement. Ask if they want you guys to fork the repo or have a direct access to it

Comment: Good point. We're at a position to dictate terms here, whatever we're most comfortable with. My main issue is I don't want my developers working in two places. I want them working in our GitLab instance. I'd also rather review any commits before sending them on to the client (to keep myself as a layer between our developers and the client).

Comment: looks like forking fits your need though you can be a reviewer with the non-fork approach too.

Comment: What is the process for submitting the code from a forked repo back to the main repo? This is a portion of Git that I have zero experience with, since we've never really had to interact with other repos outside our environment. If you can detail that and include it as an answer I'll get you the "Best Answer". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> forks are used to either propose changes to someone else's project or
>   to use someone else's project as a starting point for your own idea

[source](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)

> I'd like our developers to be pushing to our GitLab instance so they
>   don't need to set up additional infrastructure on their machines.

this as easy as `git add remote clientrepo https://github.com/client/clientrepo`. Your developers can push to your instance or to the client's instance.

If both repository will be moving(develop), I would prefer to push to the client's repo. Do note that if you fork, there is an overhead of updating your fork from the originalrepo (if you need) + the communication between developers of client and yours. Which can be resolved by mirroring. 
But if the original repo is not moving and they don't depend on your updates for them to continue developing, I prefer forking it and when the project is done you can pull request it to master of the original repo

Answer (score 1):

You can use project mirroring only on protected branches (and protect only master)

This way you'll send them updates only when merging on master, having merge request in your own gitlab, having branches in your own gitlab and so on...

You can do so from your gitlab project's repository settings.